# Python: TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not int

Tags: python, python-3.x, wing-ide

I'm trying to create a simple server to client based chat program and the issue is that when I try to execute `c.sendto(data,client)` this error appears saying that `Client` is an int but it's a tuple containing the port number and the address. I'm I supposed to convert the tuple to bytes so I can send the message to the clients?

**Server Script**

```
import socket

clients = []
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1",7999))
s.listen()
print("Waiting for connection")
c, addr = s.accept()


while True:
    data , addr = c.recvfrom(1024)
    print(data)
    if addr not in clients:
        clients.append(addr)
        print(clients[0])
    if data:
        for client in clients:
            print(client)
            c.sendto(data,client)
s.close()
```

**Client Script**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
addr = ("127.0.0.1",7999)
s.connect(addr)    
while True:
    string = input(">>")
    s.send(string.encode("utf-8"))
    data =s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

[Server Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbZNL.png)

Comment: It seems that the server print two clients before raising the error, as if your final for loop ran once without any problem then crashes, may you confirm ?

Comment: Just a guess, what does it do if you set `client[0] = str(client[0])` ?

Comment: @Trolldejo no it only prints twice  on the same cycle and I cant edit my code right now but will do as you suggested.

Comment: where is the second print called then ?
I'd suggests you to do a print as well below c.sendto(), just to make sure..

Comment: Print client[0] is the same as print client because its the only item in the array.

Comment: mea culpa, didn't notice the "s" in `print(clients[0])`

Comment: @Trolldejo I changed it to `c.sendto(data,str(client))` and I'm getting this error now `TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str`

Comment: I may be confused but c is connected to a socket since you've done 'accept' but the docs for sendto say "The socket should not be connected to a remote socket, since the destination socket is specified by address." also the man page for sendto says "If sendto() is used on a connection-mode (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_SEQPACKET) socket, the arguments dest_addr and addrlen are ignored (and the error EISCONN may be returned when they are not NULL and 0)" so I somewhat suspect that this is happening and Python is misreporting the error in a confusing way.

Comment: @Wingware I'm a bit confused can you further clarify?

Comment: I'll post an answer that includes clarification...

Comment: @Kozero I didn't meant you to try `c.sendto(data, str(client))` but to add this new line before: 'client[0] = str(client[0])`. As I said it is just a guess considering the error Python is returning to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using sendto() with a connection-mode socket.  I think you want c.send(data) instead.

Details:

The Python docs for sendto say "The socket should not be connected to a remote socket, since the destination socket is specified by address."  Also the man page for sendto says "If sendto() is used on a connection-mode (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_SEQPACKET) socket, the arguments dest_addr and addrlen are ignored (and the error EISCONN may be returned when they are not NULL and 0)."  I somewhat suspect that this is happening and Python is misreporting the error in a confusing way.

The sockets interface and networking in general can be pretty confusing but basically sendto() is reserved for SOCK_DGRAM which is UDP/IP type internet traffic, which you can think of as sending letters or postcards to a recipient.  Each one goes out with a recipient address on it and there's no guarantee on order of receipt.  On the other hand, connection-mode sockets like SOCK_STREAM use TCP/IP which is a bit more like a phone call in that you make a connection for a certain duration and and each thing you send is delivered in order at each end.

Since your code seems to be designed for communication over a connection I think you just want c.send(data) and not sendto.

Comment: But that way the data can't be sent back to the other clients in this case just the client that sent the message.

Comment: nvm I switched to SOCK_DGRAM.

Answer (score 0):

You must first convert the string that contains the IP address into a byte or a string of bytes and then start communicating.
According to the code below, your error will be resolved.
Make sure your code is working correctly overall.

```
string = '192.168.1.102'
new_string = bytearray(string,"ascii")
ip_receiver = new_string
s.sendto(text.encode(), (ip_receiver, 5252))
```

Answer (score 0):

addr = (host = "127.0.0.1",port = 7999)
s.connct(addr)

i hope it should solve this problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).